# How to force style to apply for transition / Display queuing order

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get some transitions to work cleanly, but due to the way the browser queues the various JS and display rendering threads, this is becoming increasingly difficult.

I have a `<div class="expandable">` which expands on a click event (somewhere else). With overflow control, so its content appears gradually. Once fully expanded, overflow control needs to be removed, as the content may be taller than the expanded-to height, and there are some inner elements that will need to poke outside the area.

I have three bits of CSS:

```
.expandable {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.expandable.activating {
    max-height: 1000px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.expandable.active {
    max-height: none;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: none;
}
```

Click on the trigger element, and we add `.activating` to our `div`. Once the transition is completed, we remove `.activating` and add `.active`. So far, so good.

However, when clicking the trigger event while the element is expanded, I run into problems.

With `n` being the in-code reference to our `div`…

```
if (n.classList.contains("active")) {
    n.classList.add("activating");
    n.classList.remove("active");
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        n.classList.remove("activating");
    }, 0);
}
```

The actual code is slightly different, as I have utility functions to set pairs of conditional classes, but this is effectively what is happening.

The problem is that with the `0` timeout delay, the `.activating` class is removed before it is actively rendered into the display. If I up the delay to `10`, it renders in about half the time. i.e. sometimes, the panel will contract gracefully, and sometimes it will transition instantly from `.active` to its default state.

How do I delay the calling of that last class change until `.activating` has been properly rendered into the display, so that the transition actually works as intended?

(This is happening in Firefox, and exactly the same code seemed to work just fine previously.)

Comment: Please be precise to question

Comment: I thought I was. I need the `max-height` part of the `.activating` class to be recognised and implemented by the browser renderer, so that when the class is removed, the panel can contract gracefully. How do I ensure that has happened before removing the `.activating` class?

Comment: Better you try animation in the class. max-height is not a good property to animate.try with normal height also !important is not recommended since it removes all other styles

Comment: !important is there because, when I first did this months ago, it was the only way to get it recognised, so it didn't jump from `.active` to plain as though the interim step didn't exist. And `height` is non-transitionable. All answers on how to animate an expanding panel say to use `max-height`.

Answer (score 0):

This causes delay if you set the height too large (like max-height: 1000px), especially for the cases when you get wide range of box heights.
So you can try this:

```
.expandable {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.expandable.activating {
    max-height: 1000px ;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition:  max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1.05, 0, 1);
}
.expandable.active {
    max-height: none;
    overflow: visible;
    transition: none;
}

if (n.classList.contains("active")) {
    n.classList.add("activating");
    n.classList.remove("active");
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        n.classList.remove("activating");
    }, 0.5s);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the type of transition. I fully appreciate the delay in the transition. (I only used a slow 2s for testing, as it is more distinct.) I need code to apply - or in this case remove - the class to delay only as long as it takes for the rendering engine to have updated, so that `max-height` from `.activating` is recognised.

Comment: The extended delay on the `setTimeout` works - even at 0.2s - but it is an unclean hack. Nothing guarantees that it will be long enough for the class to have been applied to the rendering engine. (0.1s was sufficient about half the time.) I want to ensure it has been applied, but not delay any longer than that…

Comment: try without settimeout

Comment: That's guaranteed to never recognise that `.activating` was present. So the expanding panel simply vanishes, instead of rolling up. (It previously worked without the `setTimeout` and with `!important`, but I'm guessing that a "streamlining" of Gecko has broken it.)